# Is it standard practice for serial communication NOT returning an acknowledgement?

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication

I was dealing with one hardware that uses serial communication.

Purpose of the hardware is

1. To set the parameter of light (on-time, frequency, etc)
2. And to turn on/off the light

The system works OK but I was surprised that it never returns a value as an acknowledgement.

I was expecting to see any types of the returning acknowledgement such as

```py
'ack' #as acknowledgement
'0' #as success
'-1' #as error
#OR any other things such as report back the configuration or lighting status.
```

As I do not have many experience with other hardware with serial communication, I am wondering if this is a standard practice.

Is it allowed or common-practice to omit the acknowledgement in the communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various types of serial communication.
The standard practice is also closely related to what to choose as a means.

For example, in the commonly used RS-232, only the following contents are decided, and the protocol is not defined.
[RS-232 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232)

> The standard defines the electrical characteristics and timing of signals, the meaning of signals, and the physical size and pinout of connectors.

It is up to the developer to decide what protocol to use/build.
As a result, there are many cases for acknowledgments not to be made due to the simplicity and cost reduction of equipment and software development.

Of course, some RS-232 also have acknowledgments like the BSC protocol.

For this reason, it is important to check the protocol used by the device on the specifications and create a program accordingly.

Comment: Thank you kunif for the clear answer. Now I understand that the serial communication (RS-232)'s standard mainly focuses on the electrical characteristics!